# Filled Mesh and Hollow Mesh, how does it work?

Tags: modeling

I'm trying UE5 to visualize my model made in Blender. Now, theres a vizualization mode called distance field which shows nearest surface of a mesh. However, for some reasons, some meshes are shown as an empty mesh. Its true that when I was modeling in blender, I didnt extrude some meshes, but created by connecting faces from vertices. Would that make this mesh as a hollow mesh?
Im trying to understand the concept of a hollow mesh and a solid mesh. Thanks
[image]
[image]

Comment: Just a first thought, not tested. Check normals, manifold mesh, in a similar way you would for printing? Maybe the shipped 3D-Print Toolbox add-on will help you out